# Getting "General" folder ID for a newly-created organization in grafana

Tags: python, grafana, grafana-api

I create a grafana organization with [m0nhawk's popular Grafana API library for Python](https://github.com/m0nhawk/grafana_api/) with

```
r = grafana_api.organization.create_organization({"name": organization})
```

then I switch into that organization and try to list all folders

```
grafana_api.organizations.switch_organization(organization_id=r[u"orgId"])
grafana_api.folder.get_all_folders()
```

which yields an empty list.

Then I try to create an initial folder called "General" to fit Grafana's style with

```
r = grafana_api.folder.create_folder(title="General")
```

but I get the error:

```
grafana_api.grafana_api.GrafanaBadInputError: Bad Input: `{'message': 'A folder with that name already exists'}`
```

If the `General` folder already exists, how can I get its folder ID? If it doesn't, how can I create one called "General" without eliciting a `GrafanaBadInputError`?

Answer (score 1):

The "General" folder in Grafana is special. It always exists, and always has the `id` of 0.

The Grafana documentation has [a section on this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/folder/#a-note-about-the-general-folder) which says that you can't use the folders api for getting information about the general folder.  It does not have a `uid`, so the `folder` operations can't be performed on it (for example, you can't set permissions on it).

To get the contents of a folder, you use the search api: `grafana_api.search.search_dashboards(folder_ids=0)`.